# Vue watch TypeScript error TS2769: No overload matches this call

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-composition-api

Consider the following code:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const miniState = ref(true)

    const setMiniState = (state: boolean, screenWidth: number) => {
      if (screenWidth > 1023) {
        miniState.value = false
      } else if (state !== void 0) {
        miniState.value = state === true
      }
      else {
        miniState.value = true
      }
    }

    watch('$q.screen.width', (width) => setMiniState(true, width))

    return { miniState, setMiniState }
  }
})
```

TypeScript throws this error:

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.
>   Overload 1 of 3, '(source:
>   SimpleEffect, options?: Pick, "deep" | "flush"> | undefined): StopHandle', gave the following error.
>       Argument of type '"$q.screen.width"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SimpleEffect'.
>
> Overload 2 of 3, '(source: WatcherSource, cb: WatcherCallBack, options?  Partial | undefined): StopHandle', gave the following  error.
>       Argument of type '"$q.screen.width"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WatcherSource'.
>
> Overload 3 of 3, '(sources: WatcherSource[], cb: (newValues: unknown[], oldValues: unknown[], onCleanup: CleanupRegistrator) => any, options?: Partial | undefined): StopHandle', gave the following error.
>       Argument of type '"$q.screen.width"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WatcherSource[]'.

This is for the following line of code:

```js
watch('$q.screen.width', (width) => setMiniState(true, width))
```

As it stands I'm handing over a `string` to the `watch` function instead of `WatcherSource<any>`. I tried the following but they all fail:

```js
watch('$q.screen.width' as WatcherSource, (width) => setMiniState(true, width)) // fails

watch(('$q.screen.width' as WatcherSource ), (width) => setMiniState(true, width)) // fails
```

What is the correct way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the [definition of `watch` and `WatcherSource`](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api-rfc/blob/master/api.md)

```js
function watch<T>(
  source: WatcherSource<T>,
  callback: (
    value: T,
    oldValue: T,
    onInvalidate: InvalidateCbRegistrator
  ) => void,
  options?: WatchOptions
): StopHandle

type WatcherSource<T> = Ref<T> | (() => T)
```

According to that you should either pass ref or callback.

```js
watch(() => $q.screen.width, (width) => setMiniState(true, width))
```

Comment: Hmm... If i use your suggestion  TS complains that it can't find `$q` and when I put quotes around it as a string there's no TS error but the watch callback isn't triggered

Comment: Fixed that part by `import { Screen } from 'quasar'` as described in the [Quasar docs](https://quasar.dev/options/screen-plugin) and then use it like `watch(() => Screen.width, (width) => setMiniState(true, +width))`

Answer (score 9):

I've had this problem with Quasar and it turned out to be that VS Code somehow auto-imported the wrong "watch" object like so:

```
import { watch } from 'fs';
```

instead of

```
import { watch } from 'vue';
```

And that's why it was expecting the wrong type paramenters.

Just a heads up in case anyone else has the same issue.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I had this exact issue. So confusing to be reading the Vue documents and not understanding why it wasn't working until suddenly I see this and realize, yeah, me too.

Comment: Anyone know any ways to tell VSC which one we want by default?